# Find a vector that is perpendicular to $u = (9,2)$

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

Attempt:

We know perpendicular vectors have dot product
$u \cdot v = 0$

therefore 
$[9,2] \cdot [x,y]$ = 0

$9x + 2y = 0$

what would I do now?
thanks!

Comment: the correct answer is [-2,9]

Comment: In fact, you will have infinite number of solutions, since you have one equation in two variables.

Answer (score 2):

You've got your equation. Now solve!

$9x +2y=0$

$4.5x+y=0$

$y = -4.5x$

Now we have

$[x,y]=[x,-4.5x]$

Where $x$ is a free parameter. In order to not be confusing, we can use a different variable:

$[1k,-4.5k]$

or

$k[1,-4.5]$

We can multiply back that 2 to make it look pretty:

$k[2,-9]$

What's up with that free parameter? It helps to think about it geometrically. What's a vector that's perpendicular to the first? Well, there are an infinite number of them, all of different lengths - plus you have two directions to go in (positive and negative $k$).

Edit: $k=0$ is fine.

Comment: alright now that makes sense! Thank you very much!

Comment: but what do you mean by a zero vector? does it not exist?

Comment: The zero vector has zero length, and therefore no direction. How can it be perpendicular to anything if it isn't pointing anywhere? ;)

Comment: Wait so that's not what a zero vector is?

Comment: why can K equal zero?

Comment: Ack I've made a mistake! Forget about the zero vector. It's actually perpendicular (and parallel) to everything. I've edited it. Thanks @DonAntonio.

Comment: your first definition about zero lengh made so much sense haha but now im soooo confused :(

Comment: Why is the zero vector perpendicular to everything? [That's a separate question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400331/show-that-a-vector-that-is-orthogonal-to-every-other-vector-is-the-zero-vector)

Answer (score 2):

I am very happy for your attempt... :)

You have $9x+2y=0$

which would imply $9x=-2y$

which would imply (assuming $y\neq 0$) $$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{-2}{9}$$

least possible thing you could do is just let $x=-2$ and $y=9$

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply draw a picture? For any vector $(a,b)$ the vector $(-b,a)$ is perpendicular to $(a,b)$.  There's definitely no need to perform any calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Every point $(x,y)$ that satisfies the equation $9x+2y = 0$ is perpendicular .

Example $x=2\ ,y=-9$ . In terms of direction there is only one vector that is perpendicular that to $u = [9,2]$ . You can generate different magnitudes for them by just multiplying a $k $ with it .

Comment: actually the correct answer is [-2,9]

Comment: What is said exactly multiply the vector $[2,-9]$ by $-1$ you will get your answer . $k[2,-9]$ is the answer where $k$ can take any value

Comment: Well, no @Jessica : that is *one* of the answers. Other ones could be $\;(0,0)\;,\;(4,-18)\;,\;\left(1,-\frac92\right)\;$ , etc.

Comment: $(0,0)$ is not correct . It is direction-less

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw Multiplying by $k=0$ also work's, since $(0,0)$ is orthogonal to everything

Comment: @Unnecessary Apostrophe's hmmm you are correct